# How to Batch Export MXD to GIF using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, export, batch

I am trying to batch export several MXD files into corresponding separate GIF files. I am using the script below but am not having much luck and am getting an error: 'Invalid MXD filename'

```
import arcpy, os
Workspace = "J:\\IrrigatedLands"
arcpy.env.workspace = Workspace
mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")

for mxd in mxdList:
    gifname = "J:\\IrrigatedLands_temp.gif"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(mxd, gifname)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you need to use `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument`

```
import arcpy, os
Workspace = "J:\\IrrigatedLands"
arcpy.env.workspace = Workspace
mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
i = 0
for mxd in mxdList:
    i += 1
    outmxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(Workspace + "\\" + mxd)
    gifname = Workspace + "\\IrrigatedLands_temp_{}.gif".format(i)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(outmxd, gifname)
```

I've also added a number to each output file otherwise it would have overwritten the same gif for each mxd, so output would be something like `IrrigatedLands_temp_1.gif`

Comment: Thank you for the help! The code seems to work fairly well except that the 'temp.gif' files only have the Title and Legends but no map images. Below is the error that returned from the script.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/IrrigatedLands/test1", line 10, in <module>
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(outmxd,gifname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 936, in ExportToGIF
    layout.exportToGIF(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)

Comment: File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 557, in exportToGIF
    return self._arc_object.exportToGIF(*args)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exportToGIF'

Comment: It may be looking for a Data Frame to export, as per [ArcGIS Help - ExportToGIF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttogif.htm#C_GUID-2D67BFB3-537F-4E76-938E-72ED9B28C029).  If you have a Page Layout you can use "PAGE_LAYOUT" in `arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(outmxd, gifname, "PAGE_LAYOUT")` otherwise you may need to specify a Data Frame name.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Cheers!